# SQL optimizing duplicate records in multiple join results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, duplicates

For example I have 3 tables:
First like 'Users', where for every single user stored his name. Second - 'Location', where addresses of users stored - typically 1 address for 1 user. And third - 'Messages' - where every user typically have a bunch of records.

And when joining these three tables - like

```
SELECT Users.name, Location.address, Messages.message FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.user_id = Users.id
LEFT JOIN Messages ON Messages.user_id = Users.id
WHERE blah blah
```

Results will be containing many duplicate records, because table 'Messages' have many records for each user. And these duplicates will slow down fetching.
And so Im looking for solution, how it can be optimized.
For example I tried `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `GROUP BY User.id` - but when results of `GROUP_CONCAT()` getting to be relatively long, `GROUP_CONCAT()` starts to return `NULL`. And I can not master it, Ive tried to set `group_concat_max_len` and `max_allowed_packet` to high values - all with no luck.

Well, do somebody have any thoughts on this?

ps
Probably important note, that in my real case, instead of just one column 'message' I have many columns, and many distinct rows with them. And my 'Messages' tables look like 'message', 'time', 'recipient', deleted', 'medium', etc  and my GROUP_CONCAT() contains all these fields.

UPD:
Seems like `GROUP_CONCAT()` drops all results if only one record appears to be `NULL`.
For example if using `GROUP_CONCAT(Messages.message, Messages.time)`, and occasionally time in one row will be `NULL`, it will return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may actually benefit from a document-storage database like Mongo, for storing Messages.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `group_concat(distinct)`:

```
SELECT Users.name, group_concat(distinct Location.address) as locations,
       group_concat(distinct Messages.message) as messages
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.user_id = Users.id
LEFT JOIN Messages ON Messages.user_id = Users.id
WHERE blah blah
group by users.name
```

Answer (score 0):

> Results will be containing many duplicate records, because table 'Messages' have many records for each user.

By "duplicate", do mean that for each *unique* message there will be a row, and that that row will contain values for user name and location that exist in other rows?  Are you asking for a way to smush all the messages into one, so that there's only one row for each user+location?  For *speed*??

If this is a question of performance, I would be interested to hear how measured, and what's fast enough.  I also wonder, should you succeed, how you'll distinguish messages.

Comment: Your understanding is right. Yes - for speed, because fetching amount of rows that equals quantity of users is much speedier than fetching data with length of quantity of all messages (10x, 100x more) and duplicated records.

Comment: As I said, I'd be interested in how you came to that conclusion.  Unless you've tested it, you've working from a bare assumption, not a good basis for a design.  If you have tested it, I'd be interested to see the numbers, and how you'll distinguish coalesced messages. If you haven't tested it, you're adding complexity to your design on a bare assumption, pretty much the definition of premature optimization.

Comment: Ive tested it and concatenation technique showed advantage over simplee joins. Seems like you have strong counter opinion, how you can support it? Concatenation is pretty cheap operation. Ive perfromed splitting in such way: Ive concatenated not just messages, but messages with id of row with message and message itself, separating them with separator. and also I does have another column where just message rowIDs was concatenated. And in such way other data about messages was concatenated - datetime and other, and with this technique I was able easily solve problem of missing data.

Comment: I cannot provide number now, because its all lost, but maybe it worth to create separate topic with profiling and discussion about this technique in common. Probably it might be interesting.